# SP13 Calculated fields in word file

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I would to display in my .doc file, by a quickpart of an calculated field on Sharepoint.

For example, i have a column (calculated field) named "Ref" which get a value automatically. And i want to display the value of the column "Ref" in my word file.

is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Add you document to the document library, open it using your word client and use the 'insert'-tab > Quickparts > Document properties and there you will find all list columns concerning your item.

More info: https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/add-sharepoint-metadata-to-word-documents/

Apparantly, calculated fields are not available. You can solve this by adding a workflow and upon list creation, copying the calcultated field to a 'normal' text field. Then use that text field in your documents.